# How to hide menu? (not 'toggle')

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page, consisting of two layers: 'layer1' is a menu, and it has z-index: 1; 'layer2' is filled with content and it has z-index: 2.

I'm trying to make it this way: when you hit on arrow pic, 'layer2' moves to the right (for, like, 200px), behind the screen. I don't know if my code is correct in this situation, but this is what I use:

```
    $('#arrow').click(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            marginRight: '+=200'
            }, 500);
        $('#layer2').animate({
            marginLeft: '+=200'
        }, 500)});
```

How can I make 'layer2' move back, when you press arrow the second time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keep track of the state, this could be coded better, but it is the basic idea.

```
$('#arrow').click(function() {
    var elem = $(this);
   var state = elem.data("state") || "closed";
   var dir = (state === "open") ? "-" : "+";
   elem.data("state", state === "open" ? "closed" : "open");
   elem.animate({
        marginRight: dir + '=200'
        }, 500);
   $('#layer2').animate({
        marginLeft: dir + '=200'
    }, 500);
});
```